# How to save programmatically created TextView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-view

I have programmatically created an Android `TextView` on a Click event.

```
public class FireMissilesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_addvehicles, null))
        // Add action buttons
               .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        Dialog dialogAddVehicles = (Dialog) dialog;
                        etVehicleModel = (EditText) dialogAddVehicles.findViewById(R.id.etModel);
                        String vehicleModel = etVehicleModel.getText().toString();
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myVehicleData.edit();
                        editor.putString("VehicleModel", vehicleModel);
                        editor.commit();

                        vehicleModelReturned = myVehicleData.getString("VehicleModel", "");

                        TextView valueTV = new TextView(AddMyVehicle.this);
                        linearLayout.addView(valueTV);

                        valueTV.setText(vehicleModelReturned);
                        valueTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                        valueTV.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,22);
                        valueTV.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       FireMissilesDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                   }
               });      
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

The above code works perfectly and creates a new `TextView`, But when I close the application and re-run it the `TextView` would not display.

Is there any method that I could use to save the `TextView` so that even if I close the Application the `TextView` would remain.

You can find the whole code Here -> http://pastebin.com/0MZRmNAA

Comment: where you are calling this code ? it should be in `resume()` also

Comment: write your layout code int onCreateView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a boolean variable on the activity class and set it to true when the button is clicked. That would mean that the textview has been created.

You should put the code to create the textview also into `onResume` method and check the boolean variable to see if you need to re-create the textview.

You can also save the information whether the button has been added in state so that the text view is re-created when the activity is re-created (e.g. after orientation change).

All that will work if you do not need to persist the information after the app killed. If you need to, use shared preferences (see other answers).

UPDATE:

Here is a sample activity that shows the code what needs to be done:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private boolean textViewAdded; // whether the textview has been added
    private final String STATE_TEXTVIEWADDED = "STATE_TEXTVIEWADDED";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) // restore state
            textViewAdded = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_TEXTVIEWADDED);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if (textViewAdded) addTextView();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putBoolean(STATE_TEXTVIEWADDED, textViewAdded); // save state
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void buttonClick(View view) { // method called when a button is clicked.
        if (!textViewAdded) addTextView();
    }

    private void addTextView() {
        LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        TextView valueTV = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        valueTV.setText("Sample");

        main.addView(valueTV);
        textViewAdded = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you don't mind can you please provide me with a sample code. You can find my code here -> http://pastebin.com/0MZRmNAA

Comment: I added a sample activity that shows you what can be done. I also added saving/restoring from state to cater for re-creation of the activity.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Initially, do the following:

```
SharedPreferences SP = getSharedPreferences("preferences name", MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor edit = SP.edit();
```

When you do the `setText()` call the following:

```
edit.putString("text", your_value);
edit.commit();
```

and before your activity loads, you could call to check if you have the following `"text"`:

```
SP.getString("text", "");
```

I would recommend you creating a **separate class** for the `SharedPreferences` operations. And also do override the `onResume()` and `onPause()`. For reference, see [this](https://github.com/rakeeb11/simple-shared-preferences), the example implements the `SharedPreference` as a separate class.

**Update:** I think in your case, you are always creating a new `SharedPreference`, rather than using the existing one, create a separate class and I think all will go well.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to persist your text view only during the lifetime of your application you can just write the code for creating the text view in `onResume()` method based on a flag, refer the answer by **Szymon**.
But if you are looking to keep it beyond the normal life cycle of your app, i.e even after you have forcefully stopped your app, you can write the details of the `textview` created(`textview` with its parameters ) in a file in `onDestroy()` of your activity. Later when restarting your activity, you can check this file and recreate the textviews into your layout as per the file.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think onDestroy() is good here, since it won't be called if system destroys process and activity is recreated.

Comment: @svenoaks , true, so we can just write this into a text file at the same time of creating the textviews. So it works fine.

Comment: yes, or in onPause() - think prefs is fine here though, no need for file

Answer (score 0):

```
try This
=====
LayoutParams lpView = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
valueTV.setText(vehicleModelReturned);
valueTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
valueTV.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,22);
valueTV.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333"));
valueTV .setLayoutParams(lpView);
linLayout.addView(valueTV );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in need of persistent storage. You can do it in two ways:

1. Preferences
2. Database

In your case, you need to use `Preferences` (you can use database, too, but that would be cost effective in terms performance).

Check this link: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Clearly explains how to use preferences for saving and retrieving data.

For tutorial, you can go here:

[How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)